# Depend on Specific Directory on GitHub Repository

Tags: php, composer-php

I need to include the [Erfurt](https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt) library in my project. Instead of manually copying the library into the **vendor** directory I would like to say Composer to download it from GitHub. Erfurt is not a Composer library, i. e. has no composer.json.

With the following composer.json I can download Erfurt from Git:

```
{
    "repositories": {
        "erfurt": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "erfurt/erfurt",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "5528b95ac3"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1" : "1.12.*",
        "erfurt/erfurt": "1.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["vendor/Erfurt"]
    },
    "include-path": ["vendor"]
}
```

Composer downloads the complete Git repository into **vendor\erfurt\erfurt** directory, but I only need the subdirectory [**library/Erfurt**](https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt/tree/develop/library/Erfurt) of the repository.

I've test it with

```
"url": "https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt.git/library/Erfurt"
```

but without success. **Is there any option to advice Composer to only download a subdirectory of the GitHub repositoy?**

Comment: Could you move your SVN-solution out of the question, into a new answer? This makes it clearer for other people that there are multiple approaches to fix this problem, and it better fits Stack Overflow's Q&A model ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: No. There is no way to configure Composer to only download a sub part.

You either would have to propose a `.gitattributes` file to that project that filters out everything you don't want (unlikely to be accepted, but that's another discussion - you could also propose a proper `composer.json` file), and then force Composer to `--prefer-dist`, which would download the ZIP version from Github instead of cloning - and the filtered files removed from the ZIP.

Or you could manually create a local publishing process of that software that will create exactly the ZIP you want, and instead of pointing to the official Github repository, you could point to your created ZIP.

Comment: Thanks! Composer also supports SVN and GitHub also provides a SVN clone URL. I've test it via `"url": "https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt/trunk/library/Erfurt", "type": "svn"` but without it ends with an _invalid package definition_. Do you have an idea for cloning from SVN?

Comment: It's the same, although SVN doesn't provide a method to filter stuff. Because you won't likely get the filter implemented in the source repository, it doesn't matter whether or not Github supports either Git or SVN as a protocol. Grabbing a sub directory probably will break if there is major refactoring going on in the source. Best way is to send a pull request for a `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sven answered, it is not possible with Git. But GitHub also provides SVN access and Composer can read a certain subdirectory of a SVN repository. This is how it finally works:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "erfurt/erfurt",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "https://github.com/AKSW/Erfurt",
                    "reference": "trunk/library/Erfurt"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1" : "1.12.*",
        "erfurt/erfurt": "1.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["vendor/erfurt/erfurt", "vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend"]
    },
    "include-path": ["vendor/erfurt", "vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library"]
}
```

And now I can run this script:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'./vendor/autoload.php';

$erfurt = \Erfurt_App::getInstance();
$erfurt->loadConfig(
    new \Zend_Config(
        array(
            'store' => array(
                'backend' => 'virtuoso',
                'virtuoso' => array(
                    'dsn' => 'VOS',
                    'username' => 'dba',
                    'password' => 'dba'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$erfurt->authenticate('dba', 'dba');
$store = $erfurt->getStore();
$graphs = $store->getAvailableModels();
echo '<pre>' . var_dump($graphs) . '</pre>';
```